# extract docIDs and documents from a file and put them in a hashmap

Tags: java, regex, file, hashmap

I have a text like this:

```html
.I 1
.T
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
.A
brenckman,m.
.B
j. ae. scs. 25, 1958, 324.
.W
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
  an empirical evaluation of the destalling effects was made for
the specific configuration of the experiment .
.I 2
.T
simple shear flow past a flat plate in an incompressible fluid of small
viscosity .
.A
ting-yili
.B
department of aeronautical engineering, rensselaer polytechnic
institute
troy, n.y.
.W
simple shear flow past a flat plate in an incompressible fluid of small
viscosity .the discussion here is restricted to two-dimensional incompressible steady flow .
.I 3
.T
the boundary layer in simple shear flow past a flat plate .
.A
m. b. glauert
.B
department of mathematics, university of manchester, manchester,
england
.W
the boundary layer in simple shear flow past a flat plate .
the boundary-layer equations are presented for steady
flow with no pressure gradient .
```

I need a regex in java which will give following:
whenever get a ".I 1" , will give text starting after ".W" ending before ".I 2"

Comment: Good, now the question is:  what pattern have you tried already?

Comment: With Java you'll need to turn on MULTILINE mode https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE

After that something like \.I\s1.*?\.W(.*?)\.I\s2 should work (will need some escaping). You may want to add more groups if the numbers after the I matter to you. Alternatively since the last thing you match on seems to be part of the next thing you want to match on, you may want to exclude it. I tend to write a unit test for this kind of stuff and then tweak the regex until it works. Maybe you can post some code to illustrate what you need exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to find the first match by using the following pattern:

```
(?<=\.I\s1\s)[\W\w]+(?=\.I\s2)
```

You will get the first match:

```
.T
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
.A
brenckman,m.
.B
j. ae. scs. 25, 1958, 324.
.W
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
  an empirical evaluation of the destalling effects was made for
the specific configuration of the experiment .
```

Then find the second match from the first match by using the following pattern:

```
(?<=\.W\s)[\W\w]+
```

You will get a result:

```
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
  an empirical evaluation of the destalling effects was made for
the specific configuration of the experiment .
```

---

In your case it could be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    String text = " ... ";  // your text here

    String p1 = null, p2 = "(?<=\\.W\\s)[\\W\\w]+";
    Pattern r1 = null, r2 = null;
    Matcher m1 = null, m2 = null;

    int i = 1;
    do {
        if(i == 3) {
            p1 = "(?<=\\.I\\s"+ i +"\\s)[\\W\\w]+(?=($))";
            i++;
        } else 
            p1 = "(?<=\\.I\\s"+ i +"\\s)[\\W\\w]+(?=(\\.I\\s"+ ++i +"))";  

        r1 = Pattern.compile(p1);
        r2 = Pattern.compile(p2);

        m1 = r1.matcher(text);

        String textPart;
        if(m1.find()) {
            textPart = m1.group(0);
            m2 = r2.matcher(textPart);
            if(m2.find()) 
                hashMap.put(".I " + (i - 1), m2.group(0));              
        }    
    } while(i < 4);

    for(Map.Entry<String, String> item : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(item.getKey());
        System.out.println(item.getValue());
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The result:

```
.I 2
simple shear flow past a flat plate in an incompressible fluid of small
viscosity .the discussion here is restricted to two-dimensional incompressible steady flow .


.I 1
experimental investigation of the aerodynamics of a
wing in a slipstream .
  an empirical evaluation of the destalling effects was made for
the specific configuration of the experiment .


.I 3
the boundary layer in simple shear flow past a flat plate .
the boundary-layer equations are presented for steady
flow with no pressure gradient .
```